# Invalid type (list) for variable X, where X is a date class

Tags: r, datetime, plot

I have a csv file that looks like this (note that it uses `;` as column separator and `,` as decimal marker):

```
Values;Date.Col
911;20/12/2013 04:05:01 p.m.
124,82;23/12/2013 09:43:03 a.m.
287;23/12/2013 09:44:15 a.m.
37,3;23/12/2013 09:45:26 a.m.
448,4;23/12/2013 09:46:50 a.m.
432,5;23/12/2013 09:48:31 a.m.
```

Anyway, I'm interested in ploting the behaviour of `Values` through time, so I execute these commands (being "tmp2.csv" the name of the file):

```
df <- read.table("tmp2.csv", header = T, dec = ',', sep = ';')
df$Date.Col <- strptime(df$Date.Col, "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
str(df)
plot(Values ~ Date.Col, df, type = 'l')
```

Everything seems to go well until the last command, which gives the following error message:

```
Error in (function (formula, data = NULL, subset = NULL, na.action = na.fail,  : 
  invalid type (list) for variable 'Date.Col'
```

In the past I ploted numeric variables against vectors of date class so I assumed that R can handle this kind of situation, but maybe the problem lies with the presence of hours, minutes and seconds.

Looking for similar errors in lists and SO didn't yield any useful insight, does anyone know what's exactly the problem here, or what can I do to solve it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `strptime` returns `POSIXlt` which is generally not what you want. Maybe you meant to use `as.POSIXct()`?

Comment: you need a stringsAsFactors=FALSE when reading in the data but this still returns a string of NAs when you apply the strptime function.

Comment: Is this a time zone error?

Comment: @joran suggestion worked perfectly! And certainly, I didn't have to take away the dots in `p.m.`. Doesn't seem to be a problem with either the `stringsAsFactors` or the time zone. Thanks everyone, I'll post @joran's answer with the actual code used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following the suggestion to use `as.POSIXct`, I ended up with this
code (note that I take away the first row of `df` in the plot command, in
order to illustrate better how the plot it's working alright):

```
df <- read.table("tmp2.csv", header = T, dec = ',', sep = ';')
df$Date.Col <- as.POSIXct(df$Date.Col, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
plot(Values ~ Date.Col, df[-1,], type = 'l')
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: This doesn't work for me!  (I know it was your problem @Juan) but it's driving me nuts.  I copy your code to the clipboard (I'm in windows) and change "tmp2.csv" to "clipboard" in your code above but I get a series of NAs when I do the as.POSIXct step.  I found that I needed the stringAsFactors=FALSE to return the df$Date.Col as characters but it still wont work!  Aaarggghhhh!  (I may even repost your question as my question).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27609919/re-visit-invalid-type-list-for-variable-x-where-x-is-a-date-class I asked the question again since the answer above didn't work for me.