# Re-visit Invalid type (list) for variable X, where X is a date class

Tags: r

Earlier today I followed the following thread and saw it answered, [Invalid type (list) for variable X, where X is a date class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27606380/invalid-type-list-for-variable-x-where-x-is-a-date-class/27607289) but the answer did not work for me!

The poster put up the following data

```
Values;Date.Col
911;20/12/2013 04:05:01 p.m.
124,82;23/12/2013 09:43:03 a.m.
287;23/12/2013 09:44:15 a.m.
37,3;23/12/2013 09:45:26 a.m.
448,4;23/12/2013 09:46:50 a.m.
432,5;23/12/2013 09:48:31 a.m.
```

I copied the data into gedit and saved it as tmp.csv.

I then applied the *answered* code from the original post,

```
df <- read.table("tmp.csv", header = T, dec = ',', sep = ';')
df$Date.Col <- as.POSIXct(df$Date.Col, format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")
plot(Values ~ Date.Col, df[-1,], type = 'l')
```

But this  simply returns,

```
Error in plot.window(...) : need finite 'xlim' values
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In min(x) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf
2: In max(x) : no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

Why does it work for the original poster but not for me?

Other comments, when I run the first line of the code then str(df) I get,

```
str(df)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Values  : num  911 124.8 287 37.3 448.4 ...
 $ Date.Col: Factor w/ 6 levels "20/12/2013 04:05:01 p.m.",..: 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Of course, stringsAsFactors=FALSE gets rid of the factors but the code still doesn't work (the second line fills up df$Date.Col with NA values.

Comment: What is your `sessionInfo()`? Specifically the `%p` format is locale specific. If `as.POSIXct("20/12/2013 04:05:01 p.m.", format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")` doesn't work, try `as.POSIXct("20/12/2013 04:05:01 pm", format = "%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p")`. Notice how one has periods with the "p.m." and one does not. You would need to sanitize your data before running it though `as.POSIXct` to make sure the date is valid in your locale.

Comment: sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C               LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_GB.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_GB.UTF-8    LC_PAPER=en_GB.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C             LC_MEASUREMENT=en_GB.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.2

Comment: @MrFlick you sorted it.  Thanks.  How would I know whether or not %p works in my local without it crashing?

Comment: Honestly, locale stuff is such a mess between different OSes so i'm not sure how to know what will work without testing. You can read the descriptions in `?strptime` where the format string syntax is documented. But other than that I don't know what to recommend.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @MrFlick I have an answer to the question.  He explains that the %p format is locale specific.  In order to get the code to work I needed to tidy my data by removing the periods from a.m. to give am and p.m. to pm (which I did by hand).

```
Values;Date.Col
911;20/12/2013 04:05:01 pm
124,82;23/12/2013 09:43:03 am
287;23/12/2013 09:44:15 am
37,3;23/12/2013 09:45:26 am
448,4;23/12/2013 09:46:50 am
432,5;23/12/2013 09:48:31 am
```

I saved the data as described above and used the same code, which worked this time around.  (See comments above for more details).

ps question answered by self just to close it down.

Comment: Didn't I mention that in your question from earlier today? ;-)

Comment: @Richard I didn't ask the question earlier today, I'm just trying to get clarification as to why the code worked for the original-OP but not me!  I followed the link above but I couldn't see whether or not you mentioned it...?  Besides, if you did I obviously missed it.

Comment: My fault, I thought it was you.  I was also wondering why it was working for me and not the OP.  My comment was deleted because someone said it was wrong, but apparently it wasn't...

Comment: @Richard I tried to look for your comment but I could only see a trace of it when the original-OP wrote, _ And certainly, I didn't have to take away the dots in p.m._  in one of his responses.  (My comments in that thread were about the stringsAsFactors btw)

Comment: @RichardScriven, I sure remember your comment, idk what happened there, but there was no need to delete it. Btw, my locale is `LC_TIME=Spanish_Uruguay.1252`.

Comment: @Richard deletions seem to happen quite a lot.  It can be quite irritating when visiting historical threads and seeing non sequitors.